# Make Robolectric run test for the current build type only

Tags: android-studio, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric alongside Android Studio (v 1.2.2)

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
>
> buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
>
> testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3'

My project contains 4 build types. In spite of having `debug` build type selected in the "Build Variants" window, Robolectric tests every declared build type (4 times).

Is it an expected behavior? How can I narrow down execution to just `debug` build type?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple. Let assume you have next:

```
productFlavours {
   one
   two
}
```

So to run tests for on flavour you simply run gradle:

```
gradle testOneDebug
```

To run all tests for all variants:

```
gradle test
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just right clicking test and choosing to run it. I found `testDebug` task inside of the "Gradle Projects" tab and it does what I need.